# Verb aspect for "be" preceding participle in AAVE

Tags: african-american-vernacular-english, aspect

In many dialects of African-American Vernacular English, I understand the following two constructions to carry different [aspects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect):

- Mama doing laundry.
- Mama *be* doing laundry.

What is the change represented by the insertion of the bare infinitive form of the copular verb, "be"?

Comment: The AAVE  _be_ construction is a generic. There's a big literature about it.

Comment: As a starting point: Mama *be* doing = She regularly does that. Mama *done* doing = She is way past doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Be* in this sense implies a habitual act. In fact, this is commonly called the *Habitual be*. It's a pretty well-documented element of AAVE. So, yeah, your equivalent of *does* makes sense in most respects. A lot of people unfamiliar with AAVE try to add that it also "means" *is* but this isn't accurate, as your two example sentences demonstrate.

As a side note in relation to your question on how this could differ in meaning from Standard English, be can often have the same connotation as the less documented *stay*. This fits specifically with what you have set up in your example. In this respect, the imply an emphasis on a personality trait, quirk, or habit (i.e., "Mama *stay* workin'...").

The Habitual be can be found in a wider set of grammatical structures, however, as my source will show.

Source:
[Invariant *be* — Yale Grammatical Diversity Project](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/invariant-be)

Comment: +1 Welcome to EL&U. Excellent post! (Did you want perhaps to put your 'be's in your second and third paragrahs in italics, perhaps?)